# Key Equivalent NSTextfield like Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

for the last two days I've been searching and reading a lot about something that should be very simple. It has become clear that isn't the case: I'm trying to make this:

[image: Key Equivalent field in IB]

That's all. I know shortcut recorder is pretty old and I've been working with the Demo of MASShortcut. MASShortcut is pretty awesome, but it's a lot of code for something so seemingly easy.

I've also searched in a lot of Apple sample code (hoping they would implement this somewhere other than Interface Builder, but no luck so far).

This leaves me with the following questions:

-Is there any documentation that could clarify some of this stuff? Or are there other, more simple solutions than MASShortcut?

-I've been trying to replicate something like the IB control myself, but I'm still stuck at "converting" the pressed keys to characters in the NSTextField (or is it a custom NSView in IB?). Does Apple offer an easy way to do this? Because catching everything with sendEvent and comparing it against a list of all keys seems a lot of work and I wonder how the apple programmers have done that in the control seen above. Should that be the only solution, are there different keyboard layouts I should be concerned about when I use it?

-How do other applications implement this so that it becomes visible here:
[image: System Preferences > Keyboard]

As you can see TextWranglers appears here, does that happen automatically when I call "[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:]" in my application?

These are a lot of questions, I'm just hoping one of you guys can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Frans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was fiddling around with getting characters from key presses myself last week, and I stumbled upon two functions that for some reason I hadn't seen before: [`UCKeyTranslate()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000122-CH1g-F10792) in CoreServices and the apparently related [`CGEventKeyboardGetUnicodeString()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-DontLinkElementID_9) (looks like a wrapper of the former) in ApplicationServices.

It seems like these are the functions -- or at least go through to the code -- that Apple's own text system is using to translate key presses into Unicode strings for display as text.

A simple examination of an `NSEvent`'s `modifierFlags` should suffice for turning the modifier key state into a string like ⌥⇧⌘:

```
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent modifierFlags];
NSString * modString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
                                (flags & NSControlKeyMask) ? @"^" : @"",
                                (flags & NSAlternateKeyMask) ? @"⌥" : @"",
                                (flags & NSShiftKeyMask) ? @"⇧" : @"",
                                (flags & NSCommandKeyMask) ? @"⌘" : @""];
```

You might also want to have a look at Allan Odgaard's blog post ["Deciphering an NSEvent"](http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2005/09/24/deciphering-an-nsevent/) about the heuristic he developed for deciding what keys were being pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction and sorry for my late response. I am going to look through all this documentation, but unfortunately I don't have a lot of time right now. I've also found: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/shortcutrecorder , seems like this is a renewed version, so I will look into that project as well. As soon as I've had the time to go through all this, I'll post it here!

Comment: I hope I was helpful. I don't quite understand your comment, but if my post didn't solve your problem, please don't assign the checkmark to it. Just upvote (arrow above the number) to indicate that it was helpful.